# How do I fix these react errors after installing @google-cloud/kms npm package

Tags: node.js, npm, google-cloud-platform

After installing @google-cloud/kms npm package in my react.js project. I'm getting these errors. I think it has something to do with the source map loader. The errors only materialised after I implemented the package in my code:

Here is the code using @google-cloud/kms

```js
import { KeyManagementServiceClient } from '@google-cloud/kms';

const AddCredentialButton = () => {

const [accountName, setAccountName] = useState('');
const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
const [url, setUrl] = useState('');
const [notes, setNotes] = useState('');

const kmsClient = new KeyManagementServiceClient();

const handleOk = async () => {
    try {
      await form.validateFields();
      if (accountName && username && password) {
        const userID = auth.currentUser.uid;
        const secretKey = process.env.REACT_APP_AES_SECRET_KEY;
        // const secretKey = generateSecretKey();

        const KeyLocationName = kmsClient.locationPath('projectID', 'europe-west1');
        const hashedPassword = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(password, secretKey).toString();

        const imageUrl = await getImageUrl(accountName);

        await setDoc(doc(db, 'accounts', `${accountName}-${userID}`), {
          accountName,
          username,
          hashedPassword,
          url,
          notes,
          imageURL: imageUrl,
          userID: userID,
        });

        form.resetFields();
        setVisible(false);
        message.success(`${accountName} account added successfully`);
      } else {
        console.log('Please fill in all required fields');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error adding account: ', error);
      message.error('Error adding account');
    }
  };
};
```

Here is the error stack it generated:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/gcp-metadata/build/src/index.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from '/home/leonard/Projects/password-manager/node_modules/gcp-metadata/src/index.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/leonard/Projects/password-manager/node_modules/gcp-metadata/src/index.ts'

WARNING in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/authclient.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from '/home/leonard/Projects/password-manager/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/authclient.js.map' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/leonard/Projects/password-manager/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/authclient.js.map'

WARNING in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/awsclient.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from '/home/leonard/Projects/password-manager/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/awsclient.js.map' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/leonard/Projects/password-manager/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/awsclient.js.map'

WARNING in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/awsrequestsigner.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from '/home/leonard/Projects/password-manager/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/awsrequestsigner.js.map' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/leonard/Projects/password-manager/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/awsrequestsigner.js.map'

WARNING in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/baseexternalclient.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from '/home/leonard/Projects/password-manager/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/baseexternalclient.js.map' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/leonard/Projects/password-manager/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/baseexternalclient.js.map'

WARNING in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/computeclient.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from '/home/leonard/Projects/password-manager/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/computeclient.js.map' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/leonard/Projects/password-manager/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/computeclient.js.map'

WARNING in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/downscopedclient.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from '/home/leonard/Projects/password-manager/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/downscopedclient.js.map' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/leonard/Projects/password-manager/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/downscopedclient.js.map'

WARNING in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/envDetect.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from '/home/leonard/Projects/password-manager/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/envDetect.js.map' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/leonard/Projects/password-manager/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/envDetect.js.map'

WARNING in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/executable-response.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from '/home/leonard/Projects/password-manager/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/executable-response.js.map' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/leonard/Projects/password-manager/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/executable-response.js.map'

WARNING in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/externalAccountAuthorizedUserClient.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from '/home/leonard/Projects/password-manager/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/externalAccountAuthorizedUserClient.js.map' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/leonard/Projects/password-manager/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/externalAccountAuthorizedUserClient.js.map'

WARNING in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/externalclient.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from '/home/leonard/Projects/password-manager/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/externalclient.js.map' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/leonard/Projects/password-manager/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/externalclient.js.map'

WARNING in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from '/home/leonard/Projects/password-manager/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js.map' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/leonard/Projects/password-manager/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js.map'

WARNING in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/iam.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from '/home/leonard/Projects/password-manager/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/iam.js.map' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/leonard/Projects/password-manager/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/iam.js.map'

WARNING in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/identitypoolclient.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from '/home/leonard/Projects/password-manager/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/identitypoolclient.js.map' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/leonard/Projects/password-manager/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/identitypoolclient.js.map'

WARNING in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/idtokenclient.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from '/home/leonard/Projects/password-manager/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/idtokenclient.js.map' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/leonard/Projects/password-manager/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/idtokenclient.js.map'

WARNING in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/impersonated.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from '/home/leonard/Projects/password-manager/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/impersonated.js.map' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/leonard/Projects/password-manager/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/impersonated.js.map'

WARNING in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/jwtaccess.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from '/home/leonard/Projects/password-manager/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/jwtaccess.js.map' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/leonard/Projects/password-manager/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/jwtaccess.js.map'

WARNING in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/jwtclient.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from '/home/leonard/Projects/password-manager/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/jwtclient.js.map' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/leonard/Projects/password-manager/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/jwtclient.js.map'
```